# Rsyslog not able to read imfile from perforce directory

Tags: ubuntu, syslog, rsyslog

I am facing an issue in an Ubuntu server where Rsyslog is not able to read any file from the Perforce logs directory.

I tested that Rsyslog configuration for the imfile module is working properly since it is able to read from other directories including /home.

I also added syslog user to perforce group and vice-versa but it still didn't work.

One workaround I found but obviously not suitable for production is to do something like:

`tail -f /perforce/logs/log.csv >> /home/monitoredlogfile`

some useful info :

`drwxr----- 2 perforce perforce 4096 Jun 11 14:01 logs`

`id syslog
uid=104(syslog) gid=108(syslog) groups=108(syslog),4(adm),1010(perforce)`

`id perforce
uid=1010(perforce) gid=1010(perforce) groups=1010(perforce),108(syslog)`

Any idea what could be going wrong ?

Comment: You need to see an `x` in the group permissions (eg `drwxr-x---`) to be able to *search* a directory, not just *read* it. Do a `chmod g+rx logs` for example.

Comment: Thanks, This has apparently resolved the signal 15 exit code I was getting from rsyslogd, but it is unfortunately still not parsing from the file..

Comment: Does the file `/perforce/logs/log.csv` have a similar permission of `rw-r-----` (`chmod g+r`) at least, and belong to the group `perforce`?

Comment: yes here it is :
`-rw-r-x--- 1 perforce perforce 190745372 Jun 11 17:11 log.csv`

Comment: If you run `rsyslogd -dn` you will get enormous amounts of debug output, but you might be able to see from that where it is trying to read the file and why it fails. Try to simplify the config to a minimum first.  Are you using state files for the module? (eg have you set `PersistStateInterval`). Also, are you using SELinux?

Comment: Yes, i'm using state files and selinux is enabled. Currently i'm looking at the output of `rsyslogd -dn` and will post back with anything interesting. I'm also considering installing Perforce in a fresh new box to troublehoot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your perforce group can only read the repo /perforce/logs you need to add "x" to that folder to allow this group to access that folder.

Also be sure your /perforce folder has the same permission. Even if your /perforce/logs has rwxrwxrwx as persmission, if your /perforce is only rwx------ then the group won't never be able to access it.

If you don't want to play with the application permission you could use ACL instead to give access to syslog user to your folder

```
$ sudo setfacl -m u:syslog:rx -R /perforce/logs/ 
$ sudo getfacl /perforce/logs/
```

Careful : once I tried that with Kubernetes (giving access to syslog to /var/lib/docker/containers), but it broke new pods (they had DNS resolution issue). I had no other choice than run rsyslog as root instead of syslog

Comment: Thanks, doing a `chmod g+r+x /perforce -R` resolved the issue